# Website always occur the following error Failed to load viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net

Recently, I don't why our website always occur the following error,but before I never receive the same errors. 
The  request IP is `91.201.66.76` , I don't know my hosting meet attack.

Error Message: Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.

```
Request URL: http://www.hicalc.com/SignUp.aspx

Request IP: 91.201.66.76    Language:     Logined User: Anonymous

Beijing Time: 3/17/2011 2:57:41 PM ( UTC+8 )     Web Server Local Time: 3/17/2011 12:57:41 AM

HttpUnhandledException: "Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown."
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.signup_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

HttpException: "Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request."
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadChildViewStateByIndex(ArrayList childState)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadChildViewStateByIndex(ArrayList childState)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadChildViewStateByIndex(ArrayList childState)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: good formatting is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Your post does not have a question in it. I'm assuming, that you asking, "Why this error is happening?" The answer is that in order to load ViewState the control tree should match exactly the control tree before post back. And yours are not matching up.

If you can give some more info as to what kind of code you are using for generating your control tree on the page, we can pin point more closely why the generated trees do not match.

Comment: Thanks!
<br/>
My problem is why the error always occurs and the request IP always is 91.201.66.76 , I don't know my website if meet attack.

Comment: Yes, it possible to cause this error by submitting forged data to the web site. It is possible that this is an attack from this ip address.

Comment: Thank! but how can I know if this is forged data? 
BTW, how can make a newline with use mini-Markdown formatting ? <br/>, <p></p>  and <pre></pre> don't work

Comment: Capture what is submitted and look inside. You should be able to see the difference in the data you programmed your site to accept and the data that are bogus.